# Django Channels Data Compression

Tags: python, django, stream, compression, django-channels

Is there a way to compress stream data sent via Django-Channels consumer?
Couldnt find any information in Documentation.
Is it not recommended to compress stream data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compress the stream data, you can use Python's `gzip` module, for example:

```py
import gzip
import json
from channels.generic.websocket import AsyncWebsocketConsumer

class MyConsumer(AsyncWebsocketConsumer):
    async def my_handler(self, event):
        data = json.dumps(event)
        compressed_data = gzip.compress(data.encode('utf-8'))
        await self.send(compressed_data)
```

Compression can help to reduce the size of the data being sent over the network, which can improve the performance of your application, especially when dealing with large amounts of data, however, the cost of compression is an increase in CPU usage.